# How to compile STUTTER lang on MacOSX 10.12

Tags: c, installation, malloc

I am currently going over the super nice book "The Computational Beauty of Nature" by Gary W Flake, where he introduces the [Stutter language](http://hactar.port70.net/stutter/). I am trying to install it on MacOSX 10.12.6 (Sierra).

**TL;DR: final solution is:**

- edit `stutter/Makefile` and `shell/Makefile` and replace all instanced of `-g root` by `-g wheel` or `-g sys`
- run the following command (`sudo` is necessary):

```sh
sudo IA64=1 CFLAGS='-std=gnu89' PREFIX=/usr/local make install
```

See **original problem below**, and read rici's answer to understand why the CFLAGS has to be set like this.

As stated in the INSTALL file, the only dependencies are: `gcc`, `gnu make`, `libreadline-dev` (for the shell) and `libsqlite3-dev` (for optional sqlite module). I made sure they are installed using homebrew, to be precise I have:

- gcc 9.1.0 (obtained through `gcc --version`)
- make 3.81 (obtained through `make --version`)
- readline 8.0.1 (obtained through `brew install readline` and having brew output the already installed version)
- sqlite 3.30.1 (obtained through `brew install sqlite3` and having brew output the already installed version)

The install fails with the following trace:

```sh
Guillaume@Guillaumes-MacBook-Pro:~/Downloads/stutter-0.16$ make install
cd stutter && make install
cc -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o read.o read.c
In file included from read.c:7:
In file included from ./builtins.h:5:
./memory.h:29:14: warning: inline function 'xcalloc' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline void *xcalloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
             ^
read.c:15:18: note: used here
        read_state *s = xcalloc(1, sizeof(read_state));
                        ^
In file included from read.c:7:
In file included from ./builtins.h:5:
./memory.h:31:14: warning: inline function 'xmalloc' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline void *xmalloc(size_t size);
             ^
read.c:54:23: note: used here
                s->token = (char *) xmalloc(8);
                                    ^
In file included from read.c:7:
In file included from ./builtins.h:5:
./memory.h:33:14: warning: inline function 'xrealloc' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline void *xrealloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
             ^
read.c:62:24: note: used here
                        s->token = (char *) xrealloc(s->token, s->buflen *= 2);
                                            ^
3 warnings generated.
cc -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o types.o types.c
In file included from types.c:10:
./memory.h:29:14: warning: inline function 'xcalloc' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline void *xcalloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
             ^
types.c:56:23: note: used here
        if(!o) o = (s_obj *) xcalloc(1, sizeof(s_obj));
                             ^
In file included from types.c:10:
./memory.h:31:14: warning: inline function 'xmalloc' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline void *xmalloc(size_t size);
             ^
types.c:151:31: note: used here
        o->d.string.value = (char *) xmalloc(len + 1);
                                     ^
In file included from types.c:10:
./memory.h:33:14: warning: inline function 'xrealloc' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline void *xrealloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
             ^
types.c:1013:26: note: used here
                        typedb = (typeinfo *) xrealloc(typedb, typedb_si...
                                              ^
In file included from types.c:12:
./builtins.h:113:12: warning: inline function 'nextparm' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline int nextparm(s_obj **obj, s_obj **parm);
           ^
types.c:1378:8: note: used here
        while(nextparm(&o, &iter)) {
              ^
4 warnings generated.
cc -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o memory.o memory.c
memory.c:160:18: warning: cast to 'varctx *' (aka 'struct varctx *') from
      smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
        gc_protect_root((varctx *) ((ptrint)obj | 1));
                        ^
memory.c:166:20: warning: cast to 'varctx *' (aka 'struct varctx *') from
      smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
        gc_unprotect_root((varctx *) ((ptrint)obj | 1));
                          ^
memory.c:474:16: warning: cast to 's_obj *' (aka 'struct s_obj *') from smaller
      integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
                        gc_mark_obj((s_obj *) ((ptrint) (p->root) ^ 1));
                                    ^
3 warnings generated.
cc -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o eval.o eval.c
In file included from eval.c:8:
./builtins.h:113:12: warning: inline function 'nextparm' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline int nextparm(s_obj **obj, s_obj **parm);
           ^
eval.c:130:9: note: used here
                while(nextparm(&i, &parm)) {
                      ^
In file included from eval.c:5:
In file included from ./eval.h:10:
./memory.h:138:13: warning: inline function 'gc_protlist_add' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline void gc_protlist_add(s_obj *obj);
            ^
eval.c:138:4: note: used here
                        gc_protlist_add(o);
                        ^
In file included from eval.c:5:
In file included from ./eval.h:10:
./memory.h:31:14: warning: inline function 'xmalloc' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline void *xmalloc(size_t size);
             ^
eval.c:1087:24: note: used here
        compx *cx = (compx *) xmalloc(sizeof(compx));
                              ^
3 warnings generated.
cc -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o builtins.o builtins.c
In file included from builtins.c:56:
In file included from ./stutter.h:5:
./memory.h:31:14: warning: inline function 'xmalloc' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline void *xmalloc(size_t size);
             ^
builtins.c:513:18: note: used here
                                p = (char *) xmalloc(strlen(obj->d.symbo...
                                             ^
In file included from builtins.c:56:
In file included from ./stutter.h:5:
./memory.h:33:14: warning: inline function 'xrealloc' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline void *xrealloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
             ^
builtins.c:856:21: note: used here
                                        str = (char *) xrealloc(str, stra);
                                                       ^
In file included from builtins.c:56:
In file included from ./stutter.h:5:
./memory.h:29:14: warning: inline function 'xcalloc' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline void *xcalloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
             ^
builtins.c:2025:11: note: used here
                *data = xcalloc(1, 8 + 2 * sizeof(int));
                        ^
3 warnings generated.
cc -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o mathbuiltins.o mathbuiltins.c
In file included from mathbuiltins.c:5:
./builtins.h:116:12: warning: inline function 'nextarg' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline int nextarg(varctx *ctx, s_obj **obj, s_obj **parm);
           ^
mathbuiltins.c:14:6: note: used here
        if(!nextarg(ctx, &obj, &parm))
            ^
1 warning generated.
cc -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o sforms.o sforms.c
In file included from sforms.c:2:
In file included from ./stutter.h:7:
./builtins.h:113:12: warning: inline function 'nextparm' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline int nextparm(s_obj **obj, s_obj **parm);
           ^
sforms.c:27:6: note: used here
        if(!nextparm(&prm, &parm))
            ^
In file included from sforms.c:2:
In file included from ./stutter.h:7:
./builtins.h:116:12: warning: inline function 'nextarg' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline int nextarg(varctx *ctx, s_obj **obj, s_obj **parm);
           ^
sforms.c:166:7: note: used here
                if(!nextarg(ctx, &obj, &asg)) {
                    ^
In file included from sforms.c:2:
In file included from ./stutter.h:5:
./memory.h:29:14: warning: inline function 'xcalloc' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
inline void *xcalloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
             ^
sforms.c:388:47: note: used here
                method->d.clos_method.args = (method_arg *) xcalloc(argn...
                                                            ^
3 warnings generated.
cc -shared -o libstutter-0.16.so read.o types.o memory.o eval.o builtins.o mathbuiltins.o sforms.o -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -lm
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gc_follow", referenced from:
      _gc_mark_obj in memory.o
      _gc_mark in memory.o
  "_gc_harvest", referenced from:
      _gc_sweep in memory.o
  "_gc_protlist_add", referenced from:
      _gc_record in memory.o
      _funcexec in eval.o
  "_nextarg", referenced from:
      _next_t in builtins.o
      _sb_set in builtins.o
      _sb_setg in builtins.o
      _sb_scar in builtins.o
      _sb_consdump in builtins.o
      _sb_cons in builtins.o
      _sb_list in builtins.o
      ...
  "_nextargtail", referenced from:
      _sb_begin in builtins.o
      _sb_cond in builtins.o
  "_nextparm", referenced from:
      _build_class_ancestry in types.o
      _slots_merge in types.o
      _class_calculate in types.o
      _build_precedence_branch in types.o
      _build_precedence in types.o
      _update_generic_nexts in types.o
      _find_next_method in types.o
      ...
  "_xcalloc", referenced from:
      _create_read_state in read.o
      _alloc_s_obj in types.o
      _alloc_ungc_obj in types.o
      _create_eof in types.o
      _create_t in types.o
      _create_nil in types.o
      _create_dict in types.o
      ...
  "_xmalloc", referenced from:
      _token_appch in read.o
      _create_string_counted in types.o
      _stream_printf in types.o
      _weak_reference in types.o
      _gc_alloc_protroot in memory.o
      _varctx_create in memory.o
      _stutter_init in memory.o
      ...
  "_xrealloc", referenced from:
      _token_appch in read.o
      _gettypeid in types.o
      _slots_merge in types.o
      _gc_prot_free in memory.o
      _gc_record in memory.o
      _mark_miscfree in memory.o
      _gc_sweep in memory.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [libstutter-0.16.so] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

There seems to be a problem where the memory allocation library is not loaded properly, but yeah, I am not very well-read in C, to say the least. Any help welcome. Note that the documentation itself says that the install was only tested for Linux, so there may be some modifications required for it to work for Mac OSX.

Thanks!

EDIT 1: in response to rici's answer. First of all thank you for the quick answer. I tried your solution, as per trace below:

```
Guillaume@Guillaumes-MacBook-Pro:~/Downloads/stutter-0.16$ IA64=1 CFLAGS=gnu89 make install
cd stutter && make install
cc gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o read.o read.c
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'gnu89'
make[1]: *** [read.o] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I guessed the CFLAGS was malformed, so I tried the following, which brings up yet another error, which makes me think we are missing something else:

```
Guillaume@Guillaumes-MacBook-Pro:~/Downloads/stutter-0.16$ IA64=1 CFLAGS='-std=gnu89' make install 
cd stutter && make install
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o read.o read.c
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o types.o types.c
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o memory.o memory.c
memory.c:160:18: warning: cast to 'varctx *' (aka 'struct varctx *') from
      smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
        gc_protect_root((varctx *) ((ptrint)obj | 1));
                        ^
memory.c:166:20: warning: cast to 'varctx *' (aka 'struct varctx *') from
      smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
        gc_unprotect_root((varctx *) ((ptrint)obj | 1));
                          ^
memory.c:474:16: warning: cast to 's_obj *' (aka 'struct s_obj *') from smaller
      integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
                        gc_mark_obj((s_obj *) ((ptrint) (p->root) ^ 1));
                                    ^
3 warnings generated.
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o eval.o eval.c
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o builtins.o builtins.c
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o mathbuiltins.o mathbuiltins.c
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o sforms.o sforms.c
cc -shared -o libstutter-0.16.so read.o types.o memory.o eval.o builtins.o mathbuiltins.o sforms.o -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -lm
rm -f libstutter.so
ln -s libstutter-0.16.so libstutter.so
rm -f libstutter.a
ar scq libstutter.a read.o types.o memory.o eval.o builtins.o mathbuiltins.o sforms.o
ranlib libstutter.a
install -o root -g root -m755 -d /usr/lib
install: root: Invalid argument
make[1]: *** [install] Error 67
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Would you know what is going on in this new error? somehow root seems to be invalid argument?

EDIT 2: I figured out from this [unrelated github thread](https://github.com/osmcode/libosmium/issues/18) that the `root` group does not exist on OSX, so I manually edited `shell/Makefile` and `stutter/Makefile` to replace all instances of `-g root` by `-g wheel` as suggested in thread. I am getting closer, but facing now a new error:

```sh
Guillaume@Guillaumes-MacBook-Pro:~/Downloads/stutter-0.16$ IA64=1 CFLAGS='-std=gnu89' PREFIX=/usr/local make install 
cd stutter && make install
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/local/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o read.o read.c
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/local/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o types.o types.c
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/local/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o memory.o memory.c
memory.c:160:18: warning: cast to 'varctx *' (aka 'struct varctx *') from
      smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
        gc_protect_root((varctx *) ((ptrint)obj | 1));
                        ^
memory.c:166:20: warning: cast to 'varctx *' (aka 'struct varctx *') from
      smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
        gc_unprotect_root((varctx *) ((ptrint)obj | 1));
                          ^
memory.c:474:16: warning: cast to 's_obj *' (aka 'struct s_obj *') from smaller
      integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
                        gc_mark_obj((s_obj *) ((ptrint) (p->root) ^ 1));
                                    ^
3 warnings generated.
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/local/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o eval.o eval.c
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/local/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o builtins.o builtins.c
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/local/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o mathbuiltins.o mathbuiltins.c
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/local/share/stutter\" -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include  -c -o sforms.o sforms.c
cc -shared -o libstutter-0.16.so read.o types.o memory.o eval.o builtins.o mathbuiltins.o sforms.o -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -lm
rm -f libstutter.so
ln -s libstutter-0.16.so libstutter.so
rm -f libstutter.a
ar scq libstutter.a read.o types.o memory.o eval.o builtins.o mathbuiltins.o sforms.o
ranlib libstutter.a
install -o root -g sys -m755 -d /usr/local/lib
install: chown 0:3 /usr/local/lib: Operation not permitted
install -o root -g sys -m755 -d /usr/local/include/stutter
install: chown 0:3 /usr/local/include/stutter: Operation not permitted
install -o root -g sys -m755 -d /usr/local/share/stutter
install: chown 0:3 /usr/local/share/stutter: Operation not permitted
install -o root -g sys -m755 libstutter-0.16.so libstutter.so libstutter.a /usr/local/lib
install: /usr/local/lib/libstutter-0.16.so: chown/chgrp: Operation not permitted
make[1]: *** [install] Error 71
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

This seems to be related to [this thread](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3228) which states High Sierra does not allow to chown in `/usr/local` anymore. Not sure how to get out of this situation though.

EDIT 4: just add `sudo` and it works, added the final solution on top.

```sh
Guillaume@Guillaumes-MacBook-Pro:~/Downloads/stutter-0.16$ sudo IA64=1 CFLAGS='-std=gnu89' PREFIX=/usr/local make install 
cd stutter && make install
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/local/share/stutter\"   -c -o read.o read.c
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/local/share/stutter\"   -c -o types.o types.c
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/local/share/stutter\"   -c -o memory.o memory.c
memory.c:160:18: warning: cast to 'varctx *' (aka 'struct varctx *') from
      smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
        gc_protect_root((varctx *) ((ptrint)obj | 1));
                        ^
memory.c:166:20: warning: cast to 'varctx *' (aka 'struct varctx *') from
      smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
        gc_unprotect_root((varctx *) ((ptrint)obj | 1));
                          ^
memory.c:474:16: warning: cast to 's_obj *' (aka 'struct s_obj *') from smaller
      integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
                        gc_mark_obj((s_obj *) ((ptrint) (p->root) ^ 1));
                                    ^
3 warnings generated.
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/local/share/stutter\"   -c -o eval.o eval.c
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/local/share/stutter\"   -c -o builtins.o builtins.c
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/local/share/stutter\"   -c -o mathbuiltins.o mathbuiltins.c
cc -std=gnu89 -g -Wall -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DREFPATH=\"/usr/local/share/stutter\"   -c -o sforms.o sforms.c
cc -shared -o libstutter-0.16.so read.o types.o memory.o eval.o builtins.o mathbuiltins.o sforms.o -lm
rm -f libstutter.so
ln -s libstutter-0.16.so libstutter.so
rm -f libstutter.a
ar scq libstutter.a read.o types.o memory.o eval.o builtins.o mathbuiltins.o sforms.o
ranlib libstutter.a
install -o root -g sys -m755 -d /usr/local/lib
install -o root -g sys -m755 -d /usr/local/include/stutter
install -o root -g sys -m755 -d /usr/local/share/stutter
install -o root -g sys -m755 libstutter-0.16.so libstutter.so libstutter.a /usr/local/lib
install -o root -g sys -m644 lib/* /usr/local/share/stutter
install -o root -g sys -m644 types.h memory.h eval.h builtins.h stutter.h read.h /usr/local/include/stutter
cd shell && make install
cc -c -o main.o main.c -std=gnu89 -I../stutter
main.c:26:9: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'strlen' with type
      'unsigned long (const char *)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                len = strlen(text);
                      ^
main.c:26:9: note: include the header <string.h> or explicitly provide a
      declaration for 'strlen'
main.c:39:6: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'strncasecmp' with
      type 'int (const char *, const char *, unsigned long)'
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                if(strncasecmp(name, text, len) == 0)
                   ^
main.c:39:6: note: include the header <strings.h> or explicitly provide a
      declaration for 'strncasecmp'
main.c:40:11: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'strdup' with type
      'char *(const char *)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                        return strdup(name);
                               ^
main.c:40:11: note: include the header <string.h> or explicitly provide a
      declaration for 'strdup'
main.c:96:21: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'isspace' with type
      'int (int)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                        if(*c && beg && !isspace(*c))
                                         ^
main.c:96:21: note: include the header <ctype.h> or explicitly provide a
      declaration for 'isspace'
4 warnings generated.
cc -o stt main.o -lstutter -L../stutter -lm -lreadline
install -o root -g sys -m755 -d /usr/local/bin
install -o root -g sys -m755 stt /usr/local/bin
Guillaume@Guillaumes-MacBook-Pro:~/Downloads/stutter-0.16$ ls
INSTALL   Makefile  README    doc/      shell/    stutter/  tests/
Guillaume@Guillaumes-MacBook-Pro:~/Downloads/stutter-0.16$ stt
Welcome to STUTTER 0.16

>
```

YEAH! Thank you so much rici!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the source was written for an old version of GCC which used its own idiosyncratic, non-standard semantics for `inline` declarations. The `inline` declaration was later incorporated into the C standard but with slightly different semantics.

GCC allows you to specify with the `-std` command line option one of several possible standards to be used to compile source code, including options for including GNU extensions. For many years, the default `-std` setting was `gnu89`, i.e. the original ANSI C standard with (many) GNU extensions including the GNU proposal for `inline`. Recent versions of GCC instead use the default `gnu99`, which gives use C99 with (fewer) GNU extensions; in this version, `inline` carries the C standard semantics.

Since the GCC which you installed uses C99+gnu as a default, the STUTTER source code won't compile correctly. (This is not limited to OS X; it exhibits the same problem on Linux.) So you need to tell GCC to use `-std=gnu89` in order to reproduce the standard for which the source code was written. (You could also fix the source but that's going to be a lot more work.)

To recompile the project, you will first need to clean out the erroneous compilation which you already did. You could just recreate the build files from the tarball you downloaded, but it seems like the following will work:

```
make clean
IA64=1 CFLAGS=-std=gnu89 make install
```

(According to `INSTALL`, `IA64=1` indicates that you are building on a 64-bit system, which I suppose you are.)

Comment: hello Rici, please read my edits, based on your answer I was able to compile Stutter on my machine! Thank you very much. See final solution in original question.

Comment: @naif: sorry about the typo. Fixed it, but it looks like you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

**final solution is:**

- edit `stutter/Makefile` and `shell/Makefile` and replace all instanced of `-g root` by `-g wheel` or `-g sys` as the `root` group does not exist by default in OSX.
- run the following command (`sudo` is necessary). The `CFLAGS` is necessary to point to an old standard of the `-std` argument of `gcc`, see [rici's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59719770/5317241) for details

```sh
sudo IA64=1 CFLAGS='-std=gnu89' PREFIX=/usr/local make install
```